# CSS nth child - 1st/2nd - 3rd/4th pattern

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a ul containing around 20 elements and need to use the nth child selector to target elements in alternating pairs.

i.e.

```
1st/2nd - 5th/6th - 9th/10th 
3rd/4th - 7th/8th - 11th/12th
```

Comment: `:nth-child(4n+1), :nth-child(4n+2)` should do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here try this:

```
    ul li:nth-child(4n+4), ul li:nth-child(4n+3) {
        color:red;
    }
```

No IE8 support for this one!

Comment: Use selectivizr to add support for old IE.